# Upper bound and limit of complex integral

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to find an upper bound (if it exists?) of the complex integral  ∫$exp(iz^2)/z^2 dz$ over the contour $z=R*exp(i*\theta)$ where $\theta$ ranges from 0 to $\pi/2$.

I have tried to express the exponential as its power series, but I cannot really see how I should continue from there. Additionally I am asked to investigate how the integral behaves as R goes to infinity.

I would really appreciate it if someone finds the time to help me out here.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the contour $C$, you have $z=Re^{it}$ for $0\leq t\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$. The integral becomes
$$I=\int_C\frac{e^{iz^2}}{z^2}\;dz =\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{e^{i(Re^{it})^2}}{(Re^{it})^2} \;d(Re^{it})
=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{e^{iR^2\cos 2t -R^2\sin 2t}}{R^2e^{2it}}iRe^{it}\; dt$$

$$=\int_0^{\pi/2} \left(ie^{i(R^2\cos 2t -2t)}\right) \left(\frac{e^{-R^2\sin 2t}}{R}\right)\; dt
$$

The first factor in the integrand has magnitude $1$.  For $0\leq t\leq \frac{\pi }{2}$, the exponent in the second factor is no greater than $0$, so we may bound the integrand as
$$\left|ie^{i(R^2\cos 2t -2t)}\right| \cdot \left|\frac{e^{-R^2\sin 2t}}{R}\right|
\leq 1\cdot \frac1R =\frac1R$$

Thus the entire integral is bounded by $$\boxed{\dfrac{\pi}{2R}}$$

Comment: Thank you very much! Just to confirm: that means that the integral goes to 0 as R goes to infinity, right?

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help. You are correct. The magnitude of the integral tends to zero, so the integral itself must tend to zero as well.